# Which one of asp.net ajax script refrences is mandatory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, optimization, asp.net-ajax

I have an asp.net web application that I use ModalPopupExtender and Accordion controls in application pages.
When I use firebug to profile scripts, I see many numbers of ScriptRefrence.axd files. Now my question is that, which one of this scripts is mandatory and which one is not.
How can I optimize my application pages for better loading speed?

Answer (score 0):

An .axd file is a HTTP Handler file. There are two types of .axd files.

1. ScriptResource.axd
2. WebResource.axd

These are files which are generated at runtime whenever you use ScriptManager in your Web app. This is being generated only once when you deploy it on the server

Both of these files are MANDATORY. So unless you have EXTRA JS code, you have no way of optimizing this.

You can use Google chrome to get rid of unused CSS rules and such.